# How can I exclude a specific @Configuration class from my Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, component-scan

Spring Boot 2.3.12 (I can't update to a newer version for reasons out of my control).

I have defined my main application class with specific scan base packages like this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {
                            MyApplication.class,
                            org.otherpackage.ComponentScanMarker.class
                            }
                        )
@ComponentScan(
            excludeFilters = {
                    @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = HateoasConfiguration.class)
                    }
                )
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(MyApplication.class);
        application.run(args);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is *both*:

A) include a package outside the application's base package (hence the `org.otherpackage.ComponentScanMarker.class` reference in the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation)

*and*

B) exclude the `HateoasConfiguration` class completely<sup>*</sup>.

I've also tried this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(
            basePackageClasses = {
                            MyApplication.class,
                            org.otherpackage.ComponentScanMarker.class
            },
            excludeFilters = {
                    @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = HateoasConfiguration.class)
            }
                )
```

That results in `HateoasConfiguration` being loaded despite the `excludeFilters`.

Another option I tried:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {
                            MyApplication.class,
                            org.otherpackage.ComponentScanMarker.class
                        },
                        exclude = HateoasConfiguration.class
                        )
```

That results in an exception at startup with the message:

```
The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes:
    - org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration
```

I can't get it to work, no matter what combination of annotation properties I try. Either `HateoasConfiguration` gets loaded despite the attempt to exclude it, or `@Component`s in `org.otherpackage` *don't* get loaded. I've looked at a few different similar questions and answers, but none of them include the need for both goals.

How can I accomplish both needs, to include multiple base packages for component scanning, *and* exclude a specific `@Configuration` class that's on the classpath?

---

<sup>*</sup> This question really has nothing to do with Spring HATEOAS, it's just an example of a `@Configuration` class that is on the classpath but I want Spring Boot to ignore. Here are the annotations present on that class (source code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/config/HateoasConfiguration.java)):

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnablePluginRegistries({ LinkDiscoverer.class })
public class HateoasConfiguration {
```

Comment: please attach a specific issue that you try to solve. `* This question really has nothing to do with Spring HATEOAS, it's just an example of a third-party @Configuration` Spring has some auto configuring elements like Hateoas. Other custom defined components by your side should be handled separately. Please clarify

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos I do not understand your comment. The question states, in multiple ways, what the goal to accomplish is. For example, "What I'm trying to accomplish is both:..." is right there.

Comment: please check your question. You specify a specific problem and then later you mention `* This question really has nothing to do with Spring HATEOAS, it's just an example of a third-party @Configuration class that is on the classpath but I want Spring Boot to ignore.`. Spring Hateoas is not a simple 3rd party library but a spring library and the actions available to the developer are not the same as if it was some custom external 3rd party library

Comment: I removed "third-party" from the sentence.

Comment: Is it possible that some other configuration or auto configuration has dependency on this class ? In that case you will have to disable those also.

Comment: @Paras it's certainly possible, but would take some time to figure out if that's the case (which is why I haven't done that research/experiment yet). I may try to create my own `@Configuration` class to test with, to see if things work as expected that way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {
                            MyApplication.class,
                            org.otherpackage.ComponentScanMarker.class
                            },
exclude = { HateoasConfiguration.class }
                        )
@ComponentScan(
            excludeFilters = {
                    @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = HateoasConfiguration.class)
                    }
                )
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(MyApplication.class);
        application.run(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that was also something I tried. I've updated the question with that detail (and the resulting error message).

Comment: Can you show class definition of `HateoasConfiguration` ?

Comment: I added it to the question, at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a solution for a similar problem myself. Dropping it here for future developers.

The underlying problem is that `@SpringBootApplication` performs a full component scan itself, so your own `@ComponentScan` annotation does not have the desired effect.

The solution for me was to eject `@SpringBootApplication` and just do what it does internally (with our desired modifications) as it's just a convenience shorthand.

For your case, try:

```java
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(
        basePackageClasses = {
                MyApplication.class,
                org.otherpackage.ComponentScanMarker.class
        },
        excludeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = TypeExcludeFilter.class),
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.class),
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = HateoasConfiguration.class)
        })
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(MyApplication.class);
        application.run(args);
    }
}
```